# Java: implementing Treemap methods on map.entry, possible?

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

My assignment is to write code that swaps the keys for the values of a map (with non 1:1) ratio, and I thought to create a `TreeMap`. So far I have:

```
   public static Map<String, Set<String>> reverseMapping(Map<String, String> mapping) {
    TreeMap <String, String> temp = (TreeMap<String, String>) mapping;


    while (temp.pollFirstEntry() !=null ){
         Map.Entry<String, String> iter=temp.pollFirstEntry();
         String newKey = iter.get(iter.firstKey());
    }
```

but it's saying that `first.Key()` is undefined for map.entry and suggests I cast `iter`. but that just makes things worse.

How can I achieve my goal of breaking the map entry down into its keys and values in a new set and string, respectively? Is this possible using the starting point I have, or at all?

Comment: It's very hard to see what you're asking. What does it mean to implement a Treemap on a map.entry?

Comment: The firstKey() method is from TreeMap, but I want to know if I can use it on the map.entry I've created (iter)

Comment: 1. if you reverse the map you'll get Map<String, String> not Map<String, Set<String>>. 2. your question is not clear at all - you should provide a full example of input, requested output, explain what have you done and where did you get stuck. The title and the body of the question say two different things...

Comment: @AndyM3 To resume your question, what you want to know is how to loop over all entries of your map ?

Comment: @Jean-François Savard That's what I'm attempting to do: iterate through all entries, collect all keys and all values separately, and then hopefully swap them in a new map (the first line of the code was specified by the assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, what you want to know is how to iterate over each entries of a map.

Let me explain you how with a simple snippet :

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : temp.entrySet())
{
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can solve your issue now.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the reverse of a map.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        TreeMap<String, String> tm1 =new TreeMap<String, String>();

        tm1.put("Hello" , "Me");
        tm1.put("Bye", "Jim");


        TreeMap<String , String > reverse = reverse(tm1);
        System.out.println(reverse);


     }

     public static TreeMap<String , String > reverse(TreeMap<String, String> tm1){

                   TreeMap<String , String > reverse =new TreeMap<String, String>();
         for(String s : tm1.keySet())
         {

             String v= tm1.get(s);

             reverse.put(v,s);


         }

         return reverse;
     }
}
```

Comment: umm..are you saying this code won't give the output  ? keySet returns a Set<String> i.e a set of objects of type String or whatever Generic type specified in the map . Good enough to iterate through and get values and put it in the other map.